# "SigPack - the C++ signal processing library" installation and run help

Tags: c++, g++, cmake, gnuplot

I am still new to Linux and I'm trying to install "SigPack-a signal processing library". Instructions on SourceForge(http://sigpack.sourceforge.net/build.html) are pretty vague but I managed to download and install all dependencies and libraries required(cmake, libopenblas-dev, liblapack-dev, libarpack-dev,openBLAS,FFTW and Armadillo library).

Now I downloaded and extracted the sigpack folder but I am kind of confused what my next step would be. There is an example C++ code on the website(http://sigpack.sourceforge.net/build.html) which I created and executed (g++ -I/include -I/sigpack -lblas -llapack -Dunix demo.cpp -o demo) but that just generates a new "shared library", Is the result in the shared library folder? If it is, how do I open the shared library folder? how do I get the final output/plot? This might be a weird and confusing question but frankly, I  don't know what the demo code is supposed to do here. I would really appreciate any help in installing sigpack and maybe working out the gnuplot and displaying results.

Comment: It looks to me like it should have generated an executable file that you can run by typing `./demo` (there have been some recent reports about "file magic" misidentifying executables as shared libraries). However it will not generate a plot - just a text-based list of coefficients as far as I can tell.

Comment: omg. Thank you so much @steeldriver! I wasted too much time figuring this out, and it was that simple.   you're the real mvp.